# PhpStorm: how to tune include paths correctly

Tags: css, autocomplete, ide, phpstorm

For example, I have such directory structure:

```
- root/
--- public/
------ style.css
--- views/
------ index.html
--- index.php
```

In index.php:

```
require 'views/index.html';
```

In views/index.html:

```
<link href="public/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

When I editing 'views/index.html' it highlights 'public/style.css' as unresolved file and doesn't use it's contents for autocomplete. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this out.

```
<link href="../public/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

I think it's just expecting a better path than it has.